# Converting excel to JSON in JAVA using poi and jackson

Tags: java, json, jackson, apache-poi

I am trying to convert an excel to Json and it should save in some local directory. I am able to save the Json file but All are getting Null values. It is reading Excel row by row and there itself it is changing it into JSON format and saving again it is going to next row and replacing the previous Json file with current row data. It is in while loop so it is iterating and replacing the file. If i move the converter code from while, only one row data is coming that to null values with column names (json data) is coming rather than 34 row data(full data).

Here is the code. Please suggest me how can i achieve the whole excel data to be converted and should save the file in local directory.

```
public static void uploadXLS(MultipartFile file, Document doc)
        throws IOException {

    Products products = new Products();

    List<Products> productsList = new ArrayList<Products>();

    logger.info("uploadExcel method");
    HSSFWorkbook wb = null;
    try {

         wb= new HSSFWorkbook(file.getInputStream());
            System.out.println("workbook: "+wb);
            HSSFSheet sheet = wb.getSheetAt(0);
            System.out.println("worksheet: "+sheet);
            HSSFRow row;

            Iterator<Row> iterator = sheet.iterator();

            while (iterator.hasNext()) {
            products = new Products();
                Row nextRow = iterator.next();
                Iterator<Cell> cellIterator = nextRow.cellIterator();


                    Cell cell = cellIterator.next();

                    Iterator cells = nextRow.cellIterator();

                        cell=(HSSFCell) cells.next();

                        if (cell.getCellType() == HSSFCell.CELL_TYPE_STRING)
                        {
                            System.out.print(cell.getStringCellValue()+" ");
                        }
                        else if(cell.getCellType() == HSSFCell.CELL_TYPE_NUMERIC)
                        {
                            System.out.print(cell.getNumericCellValue()+" ");
                        }
                        else if(HSSFDateUtil.isCellDateFormatted(cell)){
                            Date date = HSSFDateUtil.getJavaDate(cell.getNumericCellValue());
                        } else
                        {
                            //U Can Handel Boolean, Formula, Errors
                        }

                        products.setId(new DataFormatter().formatCellValue(nextRow.getCell(0)));
                        products.setProductId(new DataFormatter().formatCellValue(nextRow.getCell(1)));
                        products.setPopularity((new DataFormatter().formatCellValue(nextRow.getCell(12))));
                        products.setRelevance((new DataFormatter().formatCellValue(nextRow.getCell(13))));
                        products.setShortlisted((new DataFormatter().formatCellValue(nextRow.getCell(14))));
                        products.setLikes((new DataFormatter().formatCellValue(nextRow.getCell(15))));
                        products.setCreateDt((new DataFormatter().formatCellValue(nextRow.getCell(16))));
                        products.setPageId((new DataFormatter().formatCellValue(nextRow.getCell(17))));
                        products.setStyleName(nextRow.getCell(18).getStringCellValue());
                        products.setStyleId(nextRow.getCell(19).getStringCellValue());
                        products.setPriceRange(nextRow.getCell(20).getStringCellValue());
                        products.setPriceId(nextRow.getCell(21).getStringCellValue());
//                          products.setDefaultPrice(nextRow.getCell(22).getStringCellValue());
                             products.setDefaultMaterial(nextRow.getCell(23).getStringCellValue());
                        products.setDefaultFinish((new DataFormatter().formatCellValue(nextRow.getCell(24))));


                    productsList.add(products);
                    System.out.println(productsList.add(products));



           // JSON CONVERTER
    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();

    System.out.println("productsList: "+products);
    DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMddHHmmss");
      Date date = new Date();
      String location = dateFormat.format(date);
      System.out.println("productsList final: "+products);



        // Convert object to JSON string
        String jsonInString = mapper.writeValueAsString(products);
        System.out.println("JsonInString " +jsonInString);

        // Convert object to JSON string and pretty print
        jsonInString = mapper.writerWithDefaultPrettyPrinter()
                .writeValueAsString(products);

       mapper.writeValue(new File("D:\\"+location+"products.json"), productsList);

            }
            } catch (JsonGenerationException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (JsonMappingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    finally {


    }
}
```

Am attaching the screen shot, here you can see that, there 34 rows in excel. It is doing well and displaying the values but the last Json generated file have null values. All 34 rows data is having null values :(
[image]

Thank a lot in Advance :). Hoping that anyone can get me out of this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all you have to **re-instantiate** the Product object every time , otherwise there is only object at the end in the list.

```
       .....
        Iterator<Row> iterator = sheet.iterator();
        while (iterator.hasNext()) {
            products = new Products(); // re-instantiation.
            Row nextRow = iterator.next();
            Iterator<Cell> cellIterator = nextRow.cellIterator();
       .....
```

Products is containing single product information. If possible then rename it to Product.

Comment: Hi Gurpeet, Thank you. I have done same as you suggested. But still same output is coming :(. am updating the changes in the question

Comment: I have added the console screen shot in question

Comment: Okkay looking into your code. This might adding 2 objects.. 
productsList.add(products); System.out.println(productsList.add(products)); 
Remove this sysout line.
Also you are not using jsonInString, at last you are just adding productList values to file. Can you get a sysout of productList at the last time ? or either debug and check !!!

Comment: We have to make sure that productList at last time is having all the objects with fine values or they are having null !!!! Verify this..

Comment: Ok, Then should i keep System.out.println("productsList: "+products); or   System.out.println("productsList: "+productsList); . At last time means, i didn't get you. ek ek loop hote waqt uske values relpace hote ja rahe hai. Pata nahi kyun. Aap ek bar teamviewer me dekh liye to apku pata chalega.. if you don't mine Gurpeet, Teamviewer will be good option. please

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/105305/discussion-between-gurpreet-singh-and-mehbub).